# What is the purpose of the stochastic analysis tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-management

It seems redundant since stochastic analysis and stochastic calculus are nearly synonymous? Or is there a difference?

Comment: What about (stochastic-integrals) as well?  At least we do not (yes?) have stochastic differential equations.

Comment: @GEdgar Stochastic integrals are not the only part of stochastic calculus so I guess that tag is okay just like the sde tag which we have...

Comment: It would be nice if they were condensed into one tag I suppose.